# Can't run build_runner because BuildForInputLogger

Tags: flutter

When I run the following command:

**fvm flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs**

I receive the following error:

```
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_runner_core-6.1.12/lib/src/logging/build_for_input_logger.dart:13:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'BuildForInputLogger' is missing implementations for these members:
 - Logger.onLevelChanged
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class BuildForInputLogger implements Logger {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/logging-1.2.0/lib/src/logger.dart:162:22: Context: 'Logger.onLevelChanged' is defined here.
  Stream<Level?> get onLevelChanged {
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Below is the dependency I am using in **pubspec.yaml** file:

```
  mobx: ^2.0.1
  flutter_mobx: ^2.0.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

and below are the dev dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mobx_codegen: ^2.0.1+3
  build_runner: ^1.12.2
```

> I'm using **Flutter SDK Version 3.7.8**

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was as follows:

did changes in `dev_dependencies:`

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mobx_codegen:
  build_runner:
  analyzer:
```

Run the following commands in the following order:

```
fvm flutter clean
fvm flutter pub get
fvm flutter pub upgrade
fvm flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Note: If you are not using **`fvm`**, omit 'fvm' from the above commands.

Comment: `flutter pub upgrade` did it for me. I had some dependencies that weren't playing well.